# Please fix the box shadow on the badge hover-state!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Very annoying, but when you hover over a badge on Gaming.SE, the hover state adds an extra pixel on the bottom which creates a white line between the edge of the badge box and the box shadow below it.

**Exhibit A:** The offense in action.

[image: Exhibit A]

**Exhibit B:** The offending CSS code.

```
.badge { padding: 4px 8px 3px 2px; }
```

**Exhibit C:** The fixed CSS code that looks so much nicer because there's not an annoying white line.

```
.badge { padding: 3px 8px 3px 2px; }
```

Oh the humanity! How could one number cause such an outrage!?
Decrement it and let justice prevail!

[Just for giggles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oEI7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is no longer a box shadow/background on hover, so this is no longer an issue:

[image: Autobiographer badge with no hover background]

This was likely fixed as part of the Stack Exchange site redesign in 2018, of which Arqade's update was discussed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182).